# How to list all pages or categories on main page in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I installed CMS MediaWiki, I want to make sure that all pages and categories that are in the database were displayed on the main page with a list or other method, I tried to find information in Google, but didn’t really find anything, can you please tell me where you can see the instructions, or maybe someone already did that?

Answer (score 1):

You can access all the categories in the database via the page Special:Categories and all the pages by Special:AllPages. I believe that using [Extension:DynamicPageList](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3ADynamicPageList_%28Wikimedia%29#namespace), you can list all the pages/categories on the main page by selecting all pages in their namespaces (*main* and *category* respectively).